# How can I auto-format a git mailmap file on save in Vim?

Tags: linux, git, vim, autocommand, mailmap

I use mailmap files for some git repos. The lines in the files can be in one of these [formats](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-shortlog#_mapping_authors):

```
Proper Name <commit@email.xx>
<proper@email.xx> <commit@email.xx>
Proper Name <proper@email.xx> <commit@email.xx>
Proper Name <proper@email.xx> Commit Name <commit@email.xx>
```

I want to keep the lines formatted as a table with columns separated with 2 spaces, e.g.

```
Some Dude     <some@dude.xx>              <bugs@company.xx>
Other Author  <other@author.xx>           <bugs@company.xx>
Other Author  <other@author.xx>           <nick2@company.xx>
Santa Claus   <santa.claus@northpole.xx>  <me@company.xx>
```

How can I make Vim reformat a mailmap file this way on save (e.g. if a new name is too large for the column size)? I guess it's possible with an autocommand like this:

```
autocmd BufWritePre mailmap :<reformat_cmd>
```

but I'm not sure how to implement the actual command.

Comment: You could use a alignment plugin like [this one](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-easy-align)

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Linux you can use `column`. But we need to mark where each column ends first. To do it I add here # before each section using `sed`:

```
:autocmd BufWritePost mail silent :%!sed 's/^\([^<]\+\)\?*\(<[^>]\+>\)*\([^<]\+\)\?*\(<[^>]\+>\)\?/\1 \#\2 \#\3
 \#\4/' | column -t -s '\#'
```

You should be able to easily extend it and/or use `s` command directly in vim on `BufWritePre`.